# Ruby peek with include? acts like next

Tags: ruby, enumerator, peek

I'm having trouble understanding my own ruby script at the moment.  If I check the contents of the next position with `peek`, intending not to move the position yet, using `include?`, the position of my enumerator is moved to the next one anyway.

For example:

```rb
print @file.each_line.peek
if @file.each_line.peek.include? 'State'
  ...
```

outputs

```bash
State
```

but this:

```rb
if @file.each_line.peek.include? 'State'
  print @file.each_line.peek
  ...
```

outputs

```bash
CO
```

The contents of my file look like

```bash
...
Extension Date
State
CO
COLORADO
...
```

I am opening this file in the following manner: `@file = File.open(file)` and using the `@file.each_line` enumerator.

To me, this looks like using `@file.each_line.peek.include? 'State'` is actually causing the position to move by one.  Does anyone know why this is and how I can avoid it?

#### How to reproduce

Create a file called *test.txt* with the following contents:

```
Extension Date
State
CO
COLORADO
```

Create a file called *test.rb* with the following contents:

```
file = File.open('./test.txt')
until file.each_line.next.include? 'Extension Date' do ; end
print file.each_line.peek
if file.each_line.peek.include? 'State'
end
```

When you run with `ruby test.rb`, you should get the output `State`.

If you then move line 3 so that it is inside the if block, the output (for me) is `CO`.

Comment: thanks for trying, I will be updating my answer with a small example for your to reproduce with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the `.include?`, it's how you get your enumerator (a new one each time). Observe:

```
@file.each_line.peek # => "Extension Date\n"
@file.each_line.peek # => "State\n"
@file.each_line.peek # => "CO\n"
@file.each_line.peek # => "COLORADO\n"
@file.each_line.peek # => "\n"
```

The problem here is that when `each_line` is called, it **reads a line**. And since file position is maintained between invocations, the second time you call it, it reads one more line. And so on.

Get enumerator once and hold on to it.

```
enum = @file.each_line

enum.peek # => "Extension Date\n"
enum.peek # => "Extension Date\n"
enum.peek # => "Extension Date\n"
enum.peek # => "Extension Date\n"
enum.peek.include?('foo') # => false
enum.peek # => "Extension Date\n"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain this a little more?  Why does invoking `each_line.peek` each time act like `next`?

Comment: Based on the documentation, I'm confused as to why the position is actually being moved when it says it shouldn't: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek

Comment: Again, it's not peek that moves position. It's `each_line`. [Each time you call it, it reads a line](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-each_line)

Comment: Is that so that the first time you call it, it is initialized?

Comment: @JakeSmith: the method is called `each_line`, You call it to enumerate lines. Presumably, you want the the first line passed to your block ASAP. So it reads a line, because why shouldn't it?

Comment: maybe a found the reason?

Comment: @JakeSmith: huh? What did you mean by that?

Comment: You asked why it shouldn't just go ahead and go to the first line, and I half-jokingly responded with the suggestion that maybe I found the reason why it shouldn't do that ;-)

Comment: @JakeSmith: ah, I see :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's first write the data to a file.

```
FName = "temp"

File.write FName, "Extension Date\nstate\nCO\nCOLORADO\n\n"
```

Check it.

```
puts File.read FName
  # Extension Date
  # state
  # CO
  # COLORADO
  #
```

Now execute your code with some `puts` statements added.

```
file = File.open(FName)

loop do
  enum = file.each_line
  puts "enum = #{enum}"
  puts "enum's object id = #{ enum.object_id }"
  puts "file.pos = #{file.pos}"
  puts "enum.peek = #{enum.peek}"
  puts "enum.peek = #{enum.peek}"
end
file.close
```

prints the following. The first five lines are:

```
enum = #<Enumerator:0x007feb528d8bd8>
file.pos = 0
enum's object id = 70324339525100
enum.peek = Extension Date
enum.peek = Extension Date
```

The file position (shown above) is initially `0`. We peek to get the next line in a file, which is `"Extention Date\n"`. Ruby must advance the file pointer to read the first line of code. She does does not, however, reset the file position to zero after she has done so, as can be seen below (`file.pos #=> 0 + "Extention Date\n".size => 15`). We also see that the file pointer is not advanced again for the second `enum.peek`, suggesting Ruby keeps that value in a buffer.

```
enum = #<Enumerator:0x007feb528d8868>
enum's object id = 70324339524660
file.pos = 15
enum.peek = state
```

A new enumerator is created, as can be seen from both the return value from `enum` and the changed `object_id`. This enumerator starts from file offset `15`. `peek` returns `state\n` advances the file pointer to `15` + "state\n".size #=> 21` (see below).

```
enum = #<Enumerator:0x007feb528d84f8>
enum's object id = 70324339524220
file.pos = 21
enum.peek = CO
```

A third enumerator is created, beginning at file offset `21`. `peek` returns `CO\n`, advancing the file pointer to `21 + "CO\n".size #=> 24`.

```
enum = #<Enumerator:0x007feb528d8188>
enum's object id = 70324339523780
file.pos = 24
enum.peek = COLORADO
```

A fourth enumerator is created, beginning at file offset `24`. `peek` returns `COLORADO\n`, advancing the file pointer to `24 + "COLORADO\n".size #=> 33`.

```
enum = #<Enumerator:0x007feb528d3db8>
enum's object id = 70324339515100
file.pos = 33
enum.peek =
```

A fifth enumerator is created, beginning at file offset `33`. `peek` returns `\n`, advancing the file pointer to `33 + "\n".size #=> 34`.

```
  # enum = #<Enumerator:0x007feb528d3a48>
  #   enum's object id = 70324339514660
  #   file.pos = 34
```

A sixth enumerator is created, beginning at file offset `34`. `peek` raises a `StopIteration` exception which is handled by [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking out of the loop.

Obviously, you don't want to keep creating new enumerators. Just do the following.

```
file = File.open(FName)
enum = file.each_line

loop do
  line = enum.next
  puts line
end
file.close
  # Extension Date
  # state
  # CO
  # COLORADO
```

I've used [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) instead of [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) because for files they have the same effect and `next` better conveys what is being done.

Note that `File.close` is often omitted because Ruby will close the file when the file handle goes out of scope.

I suggest you instead use IO::foreach:

```
File.foreach(FName) do |line|
  puts line
end
  # Extension Date
  # state
  # CO
  # COLORADO
  #
```

`foreach` also reads the file line-by-line, but closes it when exiting from the block. Note that, because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File < IO #=> true`), `IO` class methods are often written with `File` as the receiver.